# Can codecept see elements in RSS feeds (XML)?

Tags: xml, codeceptjs

I have an RSS feed which should have only 1 'item' in it. I know that I can do I.see() to check that any number exists; but is it possible to check if exactly 1 exists?

I know for elements (in html) I have much more flexibility than simply I.see(). Is it possible to see xml as elements?

Comment: I did not work with XML files, but maybe you can use function `I.seeNumberOfElements(locator, num)`.

XPath locator works with xml too.
It's used for mobile testing with Appium, for example.

Comment: Yes, you would think it should work. But no luck so far. /rss/channel/item, //item, /item, and numerous other combinations all give "not valid xpath selector, not valid selector or expected visible elements '[]' not to be empty".

Answer (score 0):

```
const DOMParser = require('xmldom').DOMParser;
let parser = new DOMParser();
let elementTagName = "rss"; // set tag of your element here
let xmlXpath = "//body/pre";

I.waitForElement(xmlXpath);
let innerText = await I.grabTextFrom(xmlXpath);
let documentCustom = parser.parseFromString(innerText, "text/xml");
let documentCustomGetElement = documentCustom.getElementsByTagName(elementTagName)[0].childNodes; // your element here
```

You can try it for this [rss-feed](http://blog.aweber.com/feed).